# How to use series_divide() in Kusto?

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer

I am not able correctly divide time-series data with another time-series.

I get data from my `TestTable`which results in the following view:

```
TagId, sdata
8862, [0,0,0,0,2,2,2,3,4]
6304, [0,0,0,0,2,2,2,3,2]
```

I want to divide the sdata series for tagId `8862` with the series from `6304`

I expect the following result:

`[NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,1,1,1,1,2]`

When I try the below code, I only get two empty `ddata` rows in my `S2` results

```
TestTable
| where TagId in (8862,6304)
| make-series sdata = avg(todouble(Value)) default=0 on TimeStamp in range (datetime(2019-06-27), datetime(2019-06-29), 1m) by TagId
| as S1;
S1 | project ddata = series_divide(sdata[0].['sdata'], sdata[1].['sdata'])
| as S2
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

both arguments to `series_divide()` can't come from two separate rows in the dataset.

here's an example for how you could achieve that (based on the limited-and-perhaps-not-fully-representative-of-your-real use case, as shown in your question)

```
let T = 
    datatable(tag_id:long, sdata:dynamic)
    [
        8862, dynamic([0,0,0,0,2,2,2,3,4]),
        6304, dynamic([0,0,0,0,2,2,2,3,2]),
    ]
;
let get_value_from_T = (_tag_id:long) 
{ 
    toscalar(
        T 
        | where tag_id == _tag_id 
        | take 1
        | project sdata
    ) 
};
print sdata_1 = get_value_from_T(8862), sdata_2 = get_value_from_T(6304)
| extend result = series_divide(sdata_1, sdata_2)
```

which returns:

```
|sdata_1             | sdata_2             | result                                      |
|--------------------|---------------------|---------------------------------------------|
|[0,0,0,0,2,2,2,3,4] | [0,0,0,0,2,2,2,3,2] |["NaN","NaN","NaN","NaN",1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,2.0]|
```